# What happens with Zach's disabled father? Where did he stay in the end?

Tags: character, ending, shelter

In the film [Shelter (2007)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shelter_(2007_film)), Zach's father is shown with some kind of disability but he was never shown again in the film. Even Wikipedia mentions his disabled father. But in the whole rest of the film he was never mentioned again. What happens with him, whom did he stay with in the end, as Jeanne leaves with his bf and Zach's plan is to pursue his career and he wanted to take Cody with him and will stay with Shaun near his school. So where will the dad stay?